# Unary operator expected when opening terminal

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

In macOS, I'm troubleshooting a computer and need to run some a command in terminal. However, opening terminal immediately outputs `-bash: { -f: unary operator expected`.

The user appears as `-bash-3.2$`, but `whoami` returns the username. Nevertheless, the commands I am running fail to execute. In this example , I'm running `sudo sysadminctl...` and the command returns `sudo: sysadminctl: command not found`.

I found a few threads on scripts outputting `unary operate expected`, but I can't find anything about this being the default behavior of macOS terminal.

I've also tried switching to zsh and back to bash to no avail.

I tried to `su - username`, where `username` is the person's account name, but this returned `unary operator expected`.

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, or `.bashrc`?

Comment: The prompt isn't required to contain the username; `\v` in the `PS1` prompt string displays the version of Bash.

Comment: I concur with chepner. You have a bug in one of your rc files. This prevents PATH from being correctly set, hence your "command not found"

Comment: @chepner I didn't think/know to look there. I'll look it up now. I suppose I can look at what it looks like on a known-good machine and compare it to the problematic machine.